# generalising overlay numbers for animations

Tags: tikz-pgf

EDIT: This question only concerns the *development* stage of an animation.  Once I am happy with the result, yes, I could simply use overlay numbers. However, *prior* to this, I might want to modify the animation by splicing an additional overlay into the sequence to additionally highlight some event.  To avoid the drudge of having to re-adjust the overlay numbers to accommodate a new in-between my idea was to assign names to every event (overlay) and let tikz's `\foreach` macro figure assign overlay numbers to each.  That way I can always refer to the event by name, rather than the overlay number: `\textbf<\match-\success>{1}` instead of `\textbf<3-7>{1}`.  This is all about introducing some flexibility to help me get to the end point :-).  In the case of `itemize` Beamer's offset mechanism, e.g. `\item<+(1)->` would it help but in a 2-D, non-linear setting??

I'm trying to animate the filling of a tikz matrix where in certain "time intervals" matrix  entries are made to stand out in bold or italics or color using, e.g., `\textbf<3-7>{1}` or `\textit<4->{2}`, etc.  I would like to generalize these "hardcoded" overlay numbers so that during development of the animation I can splice in new "events" (overlays).

My idea is to define a macro for each of a list of events like:

```
\newcounter{ovlctr}
\foreach \e in  {init,trigger,match,more,success} % event names
{
  \stepcounter{ovlctr}
  \expandafter\gdef\csname\e\endcsname{\value{ovlctr}}
}
```

and then using, say, `\textbf<\match->{1}` as the alias for (presently) the third overlay onwards.

But this has two snags.  Firstly, all of the macros are taking the value 5 (the length of my event list??).  And, secondly, I would like this mechanism to be frame-specific so that I can have a different list of events in another frame of overlays.  Right now I can only get even this far with a global counter.

Can this be done?

Comment: `\value` doesn't expand so it will always reference the current number. Put `\the` in front of it. I don't really understand what you're trying to do, though. Beamer already has certain syntax like `<.->` and you can use a bit arithmetics there, too. Further more, the [`overlay-beamer-styles` library](https://ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz) might provide better approaches to this. Can you show is a MWE and how you intend to use this? PGFKeys is pretty powerful already …